# Creating a file using java in linux with the java.io.File import?

Tags: java, linux, file-io

I have tried to make a file in java using a Netbeans compiler that works fantastic on Linux except that when i try to make a file from the `java.io.File` like this ---> `File x = new File("file_name");` I check to see if the file exists and it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `File x = new File("file_name");` does not create a file, but only a `File` object instance. To actually create the file, you have to call the `createNewFile()` method on the created instance:

```
File x = new File("file_name");
x.createNewFile();
```

Note that `createNewFile()` will return `true` if the file didn't already exist and was successfully created, and `false` if a file with the specified name already exists.

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()).

Answer (score 1):

```
File x = new File("file_name");
```

never creates a new file. It simply is a reference to a file object. In order to create a new file with a name you will have to call createNewFile() method on the reference to the file object like

```
File f = new File("name");
f.createNewFile();
```

And inorder to check if it exists call exists() method like

```
f.exists();
```

Comment: Cool that helped a ton. I should have just looked up the function to make sure i was using it right.